# DCC GARCH in Stata - Negative Parameters

Tags: stata, garch

I'm trying to estimate a DCC GARCH with Stata13.  My problem is that

1. I get negative ARCH and GARCH parameters as well as for the constant.
2. My ARCH and ARCH parameters sum up to more than 1, which is not allowed by the model.

Can anyone explain me why this is so and what I can do to get rid of this problem?

My code is:

`mgarch dcc (FTSE100 DAX CAC40 ES50 SP500=, noconstant),  arch(1) garch(1)`

The data I use is already transformed to log returns $(\operatorname{log} \frac{p_t}{p_{t-1}})$.

Comment: That's strange. The initial optimization is in the unconstrained space. Once a maximum is found, Stata imposes the non-negativity and the constraint on the sum. That is the refining step in the iterations output. Can you post the output with the iteration log?

Comment: For what it's worth, I voted to leave this open. It's clearly got a mathematical /statistical component and isn't just "how can I do X in Stata."